# Unable to malloc for an object's variable that is a 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, 2d

I'm working on an assignment for class and having some issues with assigning values to an `unsigned int **` variable that is in an object.  For some reason, I can not assign it with malloc stating that there is an error with `assignment to expression with array type`. I'm not sure what this means, I have tried to use directly malloc it to `image->pixmap`, but have the same issue. This happens in both methods.

P.S. As this is an assignment I can NOT change the structs/object definitions, otherwise I would have.

I will do my best to explain the `pixmap` for `PPMImage` as an example:

```
pixmap: Three height x width, 2-dimensional pixel arrays, for ’R’, ‘G’, ‘B’ values
height: image height (number of rows)
width: image width (number of columns)
pixmax: maximum pixel value of image

//p->pixmap[0]: ‘R’ pixmap array
//p->pixmap[1][7]: 8th row of pixels of ‘G’ pixmap array
//p->pixmap[2][4][10]: 11th pixel in 5th row of ‘B’ pixmap array
```

```
typedef struct {
unsigned int ** pixmap[3];
unsigned int height, width, pixmax;
} PPMImage;

PPMImage * new_ppmimage( unsigned int w, unsigned int h, unsigned int m )
{

    PPMImage *image;
    image = (PPMImage *) malloc(sizeof(PPMImage));
    image -> height = h;
    image -> width = w;

    unsigned int ** tempArray = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int *)*h);
    for(int i  = 0;i < h; i++){
        tempArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) *w);
    }
    // issue here
    image -> pixmap = tempArray;
    return NULL;
}
=======================================
typedef struct {
unsigned int ** pixmap;
unsigned int height, width;
} PBMImage;

PBMImage * new_pbmimage( unsigned int w, unsigned int h )
{
    PBMImage *image;
    image = (PBMImage *) malloc(sizeof(PBMImage));
    image -> height = h;
    image -> width = w;
    
    // issue here
    image -> pixmap = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int *)*h);
    for(int i  = 0;i < h; i++){
        image -> pixmap[i] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) *w);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The variable (structure member) is not just an `unsigned int **`; it is `unsigned int **name[3];` — which is pretty horrid as a type.  Are you sure you need the array part?  My brain hurts just looking at it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well the issues persist for the other object that has an `unsigned int**` the `PBMImage`. and I am a little lost with the question of do I need the array part

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `image -> height` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `image->height`.

Comment: So, is the array of 3 elements for RGB colour values?  And in the second case you're effectively using a grey-scale?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh got it sorry, and yes

Comment: Right now you're declaring a member variable that is an array of three pointer-to-pointer-to-unsigned int. If you can't change that, then kindly explain what that is supposed to hold, because as-written it does not make sense. It *sounds* like you want a pointer to pointer to array-of-three unsigned int, not an array-of-three pointer to pointer to unsigned int.

Comment: what is the 'm` parameter

Comment: @WhozCraig
As per my professor: 
```//p->pixmap[0]: ‘R’ pixmap array        
//p->pixmap[1][7]: 8th row of pixels of ‘G’ pixmap array              
//p->pixmap[2][4][10]: 11th pixel in 5th row of ‘B’ pixmap array           
``` Does that clear it up?

Comment: A layout guide of what/how that 'thing' is supposed to be represented should be [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70908598/edit), hopefully clearer than that comment.

Comment: So you have to assign three sets of pointers to pointers, one for the R, one for the G and one for the B colour intensities.  The locality of reference is non-existent, but that's the assignment.  You'll need to do one set of assignments and allocations as you have now for R (`image->pixmap[0]`), another for G (`image->pixmap[1]`), and a third for B (`image->pixmap[2]`).

Comment: @WhozCraig I made an  edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will never work as you always return NULL not the allocated memory in the `new_ppmimage` function.

If you cant change the types:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned int ** pixmap[3];
unsigned int height, width, pixmax;
} PPMImage;

PPMImage * new_ppmimage( unsigned int w, unsigned int h, unsigned int m )
{

    PPMImage *image;
    image = malloc(sizeof(*image));
    if(image)
    {
        image -> height = h;
        image -> width = w;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(image -> pixmap) / sizeof(image -> pixmap[0]); i++)
        {
            image -> pixmap[i] = malloc(h * sizeof(*image -> pixmap));
            if(image -> pixmap)
            {
                for(unsigned hi = 0; hi < h; hi++)
                {
                    image -> pixmap[i][hi] = malloc(w * sizeof(**image -> pixmap[i]));
                    if(!image -> pixmap[hi])
                    {
                        /* handle memory allocation error */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

and the second one. See that there is almost no difference.

```
typedef struct {
unsigned int ** pixmap;
unsigned int height, width;
} PBMImage;

PBMImage * new_pbmimage( unsigned int w, unsigned int h)
{

    PBMImage *image;
    image = malloc(sizeof(*image));
    if(image)
    {
        image -> height = h;
        image -> width = w;
        image -> pixmap = malloc(h * sizeof(*image -> pixmap));
        if(image -> pixmap)
        {
            for(unsigned hi = 0; hi < h; hi++)
            {
                image -> pixmap[hi] = malloc(w * sizeof(**image -> pixmap));
                if(!image -> pixmap[hi])
                {
                    /* handle memory allocation error */
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

I would implement it using flexible array members and array pointers. Only one `malloc` and `free` are needed. Much more efficient as two levels of indirection are removed.

```
typedef struct {
    size_t height, width, pixmax;
    unsigned int pixmap[][3];
} PPMImage;

PPMImage * new_ppmimage( const size_t w, const size_t h, unsigned int m )
{

    PPMImage *image;
    image =  malloc(sizeof(*image) +  h * w * sizeof(image -> pixmap[0]));
    if(image)
    {
        image -> height = h;
        image -> width = w;
    }
    return image;
}
```

And simple usage:

```
unsigned int getPixelVal(PPMImage *image, const size_t x, const size_t y, const size_t index)
{
    unsigned int (*pixel)[image -> width][3] = image -> pixmap;

    return pixel[y][x][index];
}
```

Comment: Oh yes I do know that i return null, I cant get it to compile which is my main issue

Comment: @Bhagyesh see amended answer

Comment: I tired this and it still has the same issue  at the inital malloc., 
```pbm_aux.c:14:25: error: assignment to expression with array type
   14 |         image -> pixmap = malloc(h * sizeof(*image -> pixmap));```

Comment: I understand whats happening in the code Im lost why it wont compile

Comment: @Bhagyesh it does compile https://godbolt.org/z/8845hqb93

Comment: I fixed it, issue with makefile, when i run     `unsigned int (*pixel)[image -> width][3] = image -> pixmap;` it states that `warning: initialization of ‘unsigned int (*)[(sizetype)(image->width)][3]’ from incompatible pointer type ‘unsigned int ***’`

Comment: @Bhagyesh you need to use struct from other other example. Not your one.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
unsigned int ** pixmap[3];
```

means that `pixmap` is an array of size 3 containing values of the type "pointer to pointer to unsigned int". It is not possible to directly assign anything to an array type like this.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
image->pixmap[0] = tempArray;
```

This assigns `tempArray` to the first element of `pixmap`. Notice how the types of these match.

Repeat the allocation process to allocate memory for `pixmap[1]` and `pixmap[2]` as well.